# Linux Mint Debian Cinammon soundcard selection

Tags: usb, debian, sound-card, linux-mint, cinnamon

i use said OS and i am missing a window or setting to set the default soundcard. I have a builtin analog soundcard which works just fine and is set as default, also i have a usb headset which works fine eg. with mumble i set input and output on my headset and it just works, also the mute button and volume control on the headset works, but on the default soundcard lol. what i am missing is to set my headset as the default soudcard.
i also tried some stuff from there: http://wiki.debian.org/ALSA/ but it seems that alsa is not supported 100% :(
some1 here to help?
best regards

Answer (score 3):

Try installing pavucontrol from a terminal window.

```
$ sudo aptitude install pavucontrol
```

This will install Pulse Audio Volume Control which you can then access from your main menu (It usually gets dumped under the "Sound and Video" heading.) Open it up and click on the Output Devices tab, then click on the green button next to the card you want to set as your preferred device. Be sure to restart whatever program you were trying to use.